# What Happens When HttpClient.PostAsync is Not Awaited

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm inspecting some code that seems to throw

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at times.

We use the library Polly for auto retries for HttpClient requests.

- I'm starting to wonder if it has to do with the `HttpClient.PostAsync` not being awaited below?
- Would that cause any connection exhaustion?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var response = await _pollyPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => _httpClient.PostAsync(_endpoint, new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
```

versus what I "think" it should be (note the `async` `await` added):

```
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var response = await _pollyPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await _httpClient.PostAsync(_endpoint, new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two code blocks you show here are effectively identical. [Internally](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/2ac94cff75d2a63200dfab76f90e7c462f463a3b/src/Polly.Shared/Retry/RetryEngineAsync.cs#L33), Polly will `await` the delegate anyway, and multiple `await`s on a `Task` don't have any affect.

However, if you're only using Polly to make resilient HTTP calls with `HttpClient`, then I would consider using the library itself to handle that. There are examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly

Comment: Ok thank you, I did not realize that.  That definitely answers my question.